# Error parsing json in Swift

Tags: json, swift, swift2

I am having an error when trying to parse some JSON from a Google blog.

The error I am receiving is

```
'Invalid conversion from throwing function of type '(_, _, _) throws -> Void' to non-throwing function type '(NSData?, NSURLResponse?, NSError?) -> Void'
```

I have Googled around and I know it is something to do with catching the error but I cannot figure out exactly what it is, any help would be greatly appreciated:

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class MasterViewController: UITableViewController {

var detailViewController: DetailViewController? = nil
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    let url = NSURL(string: "https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v3/blogs/10861780/posts?key=AIzaSyBwmI4AzMnBmr7oSVeL0EHdzMjXV1aATnQ")

    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()

    let task = session.dataTaskWithURL(url!, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
    if error != nil {
            print(error)
        } else {
           //print(NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding))

           do {

            let jsonResult = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as! NSDictionary
            if jsonResult.count > 0 {

                if let items = jsonResult["items"] as? NSArray {
                    for items in items {
                        print(items)

                    }
```

Comment: Add "catch let error as NSError {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }"

Comment: Should this be added at the bottom after the closing parenthesis just after print(items)? If not where else should I be adding this? Thanks!

Comment: add just after the do { }

Comment: I tried this and got 'Consecutive statements on a line must be separated by ';''

Comment: @JoshCarsell try using [SwiftyJSON](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. i corrected your errors, added some braces only.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()

 let url = NSURL(string: "https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v3/blogs/10861780/posts?key=AIzaSyBwmI4AzMnBmr7oSVeL0EHdzMjXV1aATnQ")

let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()

let task = session.dataTaskWithURL(url!, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in

  if error != nil {
    print(error)
  } else {
    //print(NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding))
    do {

      let jsonResult = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions(rawValue: 0)) as! NSDictionary
      if jsonResult.count > 0 {

        if let items = jsonResult["items"] as? NSArray {
          for items in items {
            print(items)

          }
        }
      }
    } catch let error as NSError {
      print(error)
    }
  }
})
  task.resume()

} // end braces of view did load
```

Comment: This has compiled fine and doesn't appear to be showing any errors thank you, except the expected output is not shown :S

Comment: Afraid to say it's still not printing the blog information :(

Comment: we forgot call this task.resume(). place this just before viewdidload end.

Comment: Ahh yes! Knew there was something missing, think that should work now one second

Comment: Thanks ever so much, this has now solved my issues and the code is compiling fine while displaying the correct results.

Answer (score 0):

Try This,

```
do {
        let jsonResult = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as! NSDictionary
        if jsonResult.count > 0 {

            if let items = jsonResult["items"] as? NSArray {
                for items in items {
                    print(items)

                }
            }
   }catch{
            print("Something wrong")
        }
```

and replace this line

```
let task = session.dataTaskWithURL(url!, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
```

with

```
let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request) { (data:NSData?, response:NSURLResponse?, error:NSError?) -> Void in
```

Comment: Hi, I tried this and received the same two errors, 'Invalid conversion from throwing etc..' and 'Consecutive statements on a line must be separated by ';'

Comment: If its not working please upload a screenshot of your error on the code window

Comment: Hi I left out this bracket you removed from the end of the first line initially anyway, have tried this updated code too, still receiving the same two errors :(

Comment: Hi, got the same 'consecutive statements on line must be separated' on the catch and 'unresolved use of identifier 'request' on the try line

Comment: try my anwser @JoshCarsell